# nginx + php-fpm chdir not working

Tags: php, nginx, chroot, chdir, fpm

I'm meeting a problem with getting my nginx and php-fpm working.

I'm getting an error 504 when I try to access my application.

I have a structure like this;

```
data/mybesite/
 |    
 |---revisions/
 |
 |---shared/
 |
 |---released/
       |---web/
       |---app/
       |---.../
```

in my fpm pool I have the following:

```
chroot = /data/mybesite/
chdir = /released/web/
```

in my nginx:

```
root /data/mywebsite/released/web/;

fastcgi_param                  SCRIPT_FILENAME              /web/released$fastcgi_script_name;
```

So what I want is to chroot on `data/mybesite/` and the application located in `data/mywebsite/released/web/` to access files in the folder shared.

nb: I don't know if it is worth mentioning but I have a soft link like this `released -> /data/mywebsite/revisions/...`